# Java: Please insert "}" to complete classbody

Tags: java, class, syntax, syntax-error

I wrote a little test program but I'm experiencing a syntax error in my closing tags...

Here's the code

```
public class Test 
{
    AudioFile file = null;
    String vbb = "";
    File f;

    public Test()
    {
        openFile();
    }   

    public File openFile()
    {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
        if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            return null;
        } else {
            f = fc.getCurrentDirectory();
            return f;
        }
    }

    f = new File(openFile());
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for(File fi : files)
    {
        try {
            file = (AudioFile) AudioFileIO.read(new File(fi.getAbsolutePath()));
            MP3AudioHeader ah = (MP3AudioHeader) file.getAudioHeader();
            String time = ah.getTrackLengthAsString();
            String rate = ah.getBitRate();
            boolean vb = ah.isVariableBitRate();
            if(vb == false)
            {
                vbb = "Nee";
            } else {
                vbb = "Ja";
            }
            Tag tag = file.getTag();
            String artist = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST);
            String title = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);
            String album = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
            String genre = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.GENRE);
            String temo = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.BPM);
            String path = fi.getAbsolutePath();

            System.out.println("Duur: " + time + "\nVariabele bitrate: " + vbb + "\nArtiest: " + artist +"\nTitel: " + title
                    + "\nAlbum: " + album + "\nGenre: " + genre + "\nBPM: " + temo + "\nBitrate: " + rate + " kbps\nPad: " + path);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.print("FOUT");
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler gives an error at the LATEST closing accolade:
"Please insert } to complete classbody"
And also at the last accolade of the "openFile()" method...

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put your code inside a method, not loose inside the class.

Comment: This doesn't look like it will compile as-is. It isn't correct Java.

Comment: @clvrmnky: Hence the question, where he mentions he has a compile error?  What did he say that makes you think he thought it was compiling?

Comment: @Mark P, the problem had little to do with braces, and the compiler errors were pretty clear. Perhaps I should have been more clear: "Have you tried to follow the advice of the compiler?" i.e., there were multiple syntax errors that had to be resolved that had little to do with how the methods were in the class body.

Comment: @clvrmnky: You say the problem has little to do with braces, but you also say the OP should follow the advice of the compiler.  Well according to the OP, the compiler explicitly *says* that **it's a problem with braces** ("Please insert }...") so I think you have to choose one or the other :-).  When you're really new to a language sometimes compiler error messages just seem like they're in another language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have

```
f = new File ...
...
catch ( .. )
{
  ....
}
```

You want to wrap that in

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
....
}
```

You cannot have a code block in a class definition.  At the very top of the class, those variable declarations are declarations of class members with default visibility.

Comment: Due to the nature of the code the OP has written, it doesn't belong in the `main` method, but rather an instance method or the constructor.

Comment: I'm not too sure of that.  By the looks of the code, it should be a main method.  It's executing the bulk of the logic in the block and doesn't really return anything useful.  It's mostly printing.  I think the Test constructor is actually extraneous.

Comment: I don't disagree, I was just trying to say that the way he had written it wouldn't work in a main method: he'd have to change `f` to be static or a local variable, for example.

Comment: Yes, from the looks of it, he's not writing a class but just some functionality he/she would like in Java.  Probably, all the methods and variables should be static.

Answer (score 5):

```
    f = new File(openFile());
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    for(File fi : files)
    {
        //...
    }
```

This whole block of logic is not in a method.  It needs to be in a method or constructor.

Answer (score 3):

All the code starting with the line

```
f = new File(openFile());
```

is outside of any method. This is not legal Java: statements must be enclosed in a block or method body.

Answer (score 0):

everything below

```
public File openFile()
{
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int result = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
    if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
    {
        return null;
    } else {
        f = fc.getCurrentDirectory();
        return f;
    }
}
```

is not enclosed within a method body but is rather lurking in the class body.  remove the outer closing brace above.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've put the "roaming" code in a method and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not in a method. It needs to be in a method or a static block. Guessing your intent you can put it in the constructor like :

```
public class Test 
{
    AudioFile file = null;
    String vbb = "";
    File f;

    public Test()
    {
        openFile();

        f = new File(openFile());
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        for(File fi : files)
        {
            try {
                file = (AudioFile) AudioFileIO.read(new File(fi.getAbsolutePath()));
                MP3AudioHeader ah = (MP3AudioHeader) file.getAudioHeader();
                String time = ah.getTrackLengthAsString();
                String rate = ah.getBitRate();
                boolean vb = ah.isVariableBitRate();
                if(vb == false)
                {
                    vbb = "Nee";
                } else {
                    vbb = "Ja";
                }
                Tag tag = file.getTag();
                String artist = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST);
                String title = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.TITLE);
                String album = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ALBUM);
                String genre = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.GENRE);
                String temo = tag.getFirst(FieldKey.BPM);
                String path = fi.getAbsolutePath();

                System.out.println("Duur: " + time + "\nVariabele bitrate: " + vbb + "\nArtiest: " + artist +"\nTitel: " + title
                        + "\nAlbum: " + album + "\nGenre: " + genre + "\nBPM: " + temo + "\nBitrate: " + rate + " kbps\nPad: " + path);

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.err.print("FOUT");
            }
        }


    }   

    public File openFile()
    {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
        if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            return null;
        } else {
            f = fc.getCurrentDirectory();
            return f;
        }
    }

}
```